# How can I gracefully iterate over a key - value hash generated from JSON containing values set to 'undef' and 'null'?

Tags: json, perl, null, undef

I am pulling a third party's json response and sometimes the values of the fields are literally 'undef' or 'null'. If I try to do a print of the key and value of each object in this json, whenever there is a undef value it will throw an uninitialized value error.

Is there something I can add to the initial $json->decode to change those null/undefs to something perl can handle? Or maybe even just have it exclude the value pairs that are null/undef from being deposited into $json_text?

```
my $json_text = $json->decode($content);

foreach my $article(@{$json_text->{data}->{articles}}){
      while (my($k, $v) = each ($article)){
        print "$k => $v\n";
      }
}
```

Comment: err, decode *is* doing that; it is changing JSON nulls to perl undefs.  just test with `defined($v)`

Comment: Perl handles undef just fine. If your json actually contains a literal, quoted "undef", it's badly broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_ // ""` will translate `undef` values to empty string,

```
my $json_text = $json->decode($content);

foreach my $article (@{$json_text->{data}->{articles}}) {
      while (my($k, $v) = map { $_ // "" } each %$article) {
        print "$k => $v\n";
      }
}
```

Comment: This superfluously checks all the hash *keys* for definedness as well as the values.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running a version of Perl that allows `each` to be applied to a hash *reference*, you can also use the *defined-or* operator `//`.

An expression like `a // b` evaluates to `a` if `a` is defined, otherwise `b`.

You can use it like this.

```
my $json_text = $json->decode($content);

for my $article (@{$json_text->{data}{articles}}) {
  while (my ($k, $v) = each $article) {
    printf "%s => %s\n", $k, $v // 'null';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `printf "%s => %s\n", $k || "empty", $v || "empty";`

or even

```
$k ||= "empty";
$v ||= "empty";
print "$k => $v\n";
```

Comment: In v10 and later, the defined-or operator `//` can be used. It works like `||` except that it tests for definedness, not truth. This prevents you from changing the legit values `0` (number zero) or `''` (the empty string). On earlier perls, `$x = defined $x ? $x : "empty"` or `$x = "empty" unless defined $x` could be used.